# Saving hashed passwords - Safe?

Tags: python

Would a Python script like this be safe to use? There would be a file "theFile" on the disk:

```
myPassHash = theFile.read()
enteredPassword = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
enteredHash = hashlib.sha512(enteredPassword)
if myPassHash == enteredHash:
    print "Correct!"
else:
    print "Incorrect!"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like it's susceptible to a rainbow table attack, because you're not salting the password.

For more information on salts (and why it's a bad idea to roll your own authentication mechanism), read [Eric Lippert's fabulous series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/salt/) on password salting.

Comment: Okay. Just a random question I'm sure you can answer: If even million-character strings can be hashed to the same length, must thousands of possible strings result in the same hash? So at some number of characters, a rainbow table usually fails?

Comment: Yes, it's possible for a number of different strings to hash to the same result (collisions). However, that works *in favor* of a rainbow table - you only have to match *one* of them. If `password` and `longPasswordWithNumbers12345AndSymbols!@#$%` hashed to the same result, then you'd be able to log into that site with either password!

Comment: This is partly where a salt comes in - even if `hash(A)` and `hash(B)` have the same result, it's unlikely that `hash(salt + A)` and `hash(salt + B)` will.

Comment: Salts protect you from rainbow tables, but not from brute force attacks. General purpose hash functions shouldn't be used for password storage.

Comment: SHA-2 is a cryptographic hash function. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: SHA-2 is a **general purpose** cryptographic hash function. As such, one of its ideal properties is to be easy and fast to compute a hash. This is desirable for things like data integrity checking, but not for password storage, since it means someone attempting a brute force attack can do a great number of attempts in a short period of time. For password storage you want a hash function specifically designed for that, one that's complex, slow, and adaptable as faster computers become available.

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use a hashing algorithm for password you probably want to use a salt as well.  Take a look at this article about salts: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using a general purpose hash algorithm like SHA-2 for storing passwords, even with salts. Salts protect you from rainbow tables, but they won't protect you from brute-force attacks. Processing is cheap and easily available these days for anyone with a credit card, and if your database is compromised, even with salts someone can crack the poorly chosen passwords easily.

There are specific hash functions created for the purpose of storing passwords. The difference is that it allows you to adjust how many cycles of the encryption algorithm are used to generate your hash, and therefore how expensive it is to do it, or how long it takes. This makes brute force attacks much harder, even when much faster computers become available.

One of them is [bcrypt](http://static.usenix.org/events/usenix99/provos/provos_html/index.html), available for Python [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-bcrypt/):

```
>>> import bcrypt
>>> h = bcrypt.hashpw('lero', bcrypt.gensalt(10))
>>> j = bcrypt.hashpw('lero', bcrypt.gensalt(12))
>>> h
'$2a$10$FhdV1LfOPfxvHcwbWSZLiupbUL8i.som6GyqWue6VBwVgKK9cZcRi'
>>> j
'$2a$12$bgZ1eFD/VTGWUtA8jhnUcO7JjpIpBRjbNpQ9DcYQvtyQV4XsjAXU6'
>>>
```

The call to bcrypt.gensalt() determines how complex the generated hash is. As you can see, they both generate a hash, but the call with bcrypt.gensalt(12) takes longer. As computers get faster, you can increase that and regenerate the hashes from time to time, so brute force attacks won't ever be effective.

Answer (score 0):

Check out something like this

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/understanding-hash-functions-and-keeping-passwords-safe/

This is PHP, but it applies the same. You need a salt, at minimum

Answer (score 0):

Use [passlib](https://code.google.com/p/passlib/), don't write your own password crypto / checking code.